# Net fluxes of carbon caused by humans

Tags: atmosphere, oceanography, carbon-cycle, biomass, anthropocene

The current and future amount of carbon (in the form of carbon dioxide) in the atmosphere and the hydrosphere is what currently concerns and occupies many people.

I am looking for a big picture of the net fluxes between different carriers of carbon that gives a good idea where the [anthropogenic CO<sub>2</sub> emissions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Carbon_dioxide_in_Earth%27s_atmosphere#/Atmospheric_carbon_dioxide_and_the_carbon_cycle) (and other greenhouse gases) actually did come from (compared to e.g. 1500, 1800, 1900, 1950 and 2000).

So I am looking for rough (and possibly estimated) numbers like these - optimally in an overview, so the numbers sum up to 100:

- p<sub>1</sub>% by fossil fuel burning
- p<sub>2</sub>% from the natural biosphere (which decreased), esp. deforestation
- p<sub>3</sub>% from cultivated biosphere (which increased), incl. methane emissions from cattle
- p<sub>4</sub>% from industrial abiotic chemical processes, e.g. cement production
- p<sub>k</sub>% other important sources with p<sub>k</sub> > 1%?
- p<sub>6</sub>% other?

Answer (score 3):

There are various [charts](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&hs=yEi&biw=1203&bih=643&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=YHRDXaWOEKvH0PEPi6Wt2Ao&q=fossil+cement+%22land+use%22+CO2+emissions&oq=fossil+cement+%22land+use%22+CO2+emissions) but not exactly what you want. This one combines burning, industry and cement but shows land sources and sinks separately:
[image]
[CarbonBrief](https://www.carbonbrief.org/what-global-co2-emissions-2016-mean-climate-change),  Le Quéré, C. et al. ([2016](https://doi.org/10.5194/essd-8-605-2016))

Comment: +1 But please don't link to random Dropboxes rather than the actual open-access paper.